# Convert base64-encoded string into hex int

Tags: python, base64, encode

I have a base64-encoded nonce as a 24-character string:

```
nonce = "azRzAi5rm1ry/l0drnz1vw=="
```

And I want a 16-byte int:

```
0x6b3473022e6b9b5af2fe5d1dae7cf5bf
```

My best attempt:

```
from base64 import b64decode

b64decode(nonce)

>> b'k4s\x02.k\x9bZ\xf2\xfe]\x1d\xae|\xf5\xbf'
```

How can I get an integer from the base64 string?

Comment: `binascii.hexlify(b64decode(nonce))` or in Python3, `b64decode(nonce).hex()`.

Answer (score 5):

To get an integer from the string, you can do:

#### Code:

```
# Python 3
decoded = int.from_bytes(b64decode(nonce), 'big')

# Python 2
decoded = int(b64decode(nonce).encode('hex'), 16)
```

#### Test Code:

```
nonce = "azRzAi5rm1ry/l0drnz1vw=="
nonce_hex = 0x6b3473022e6b9b5af2fe5d1dae7cf5bf
from base64 import b64decode

decoded = int.from_bytes(b64decode(nonce), 'big')

# PY 2
# decoded = int(b64decode(nonce).encode('hex'), 16)

assert decoded == nonce_hex
print(hex(decoded))
```

#### Results:

```
0x6b3473022e6b9b5af2fe5d1dae7cf5bf
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert like this:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> decoded = base64.b64decode(nonce)
>>> b_string = codecs.encode(decoded, 'hex')
>>> b_string
b'6b3473022e6b9b5af2fe5d1dae7cf5bf'
```